# Display Treeview inserts for each item

Tags: python, insert, treeview

I'm looking to show the data inserted to a treeview after each insert of a loop, instead of showing all at the end of iterating.

The code iterates through a set of records and creates a payload for an API insert. The print line prints each row to the terminal, but the treeview only shows all the rows after the loop completes.

I'd like to see each row presented to the treeview (on-screen) after each row is inserted.

```
    for record in training_df.to_dict(orient='records'):
        record_data = {'records': [record]}
        payload_json = json.dumps(record_data)
        print(payload_json)
        data_tree.insert('', 'end', text=str(payload_json), values=(count))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and the treeview updates after each record id received.

simply add

```
data_tree.update()
```

Hopefully it may help someone else having the same problem